# How to right-side annotate a bracketed-together set of items in cases environment?

Tags: align, cases

How to right-side annotate a bracketed-together set of items in the `align` environment, `cases` sub-environment?

E.g. how to put an annotation such as "(Fermat)" where the following code would put a number for the equation pair:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
first equation\\
second equation\\
\end{cases}
 \end{align}
```

? (I realise to get rid of the number, I have to change `align` to `align*`)

Comment: Please consider to upvote answers you find useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using `amsmath`, don't bother adding `*`; instead, put `\tag{Fermat}` just before `\end{align}` and that will be placed where the equation number usually goes.

actually, you should just use `equation` instead of `align` since `cases` is a single entity.

you also don't need (or want) the second `\\` before `\end{cases}`.

Comment: Thanks. `tag{Fermat}` before `\end{align}` - shortest solution of all so far! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could be use `rcases` from the `mathtools` package, or you could use the `\left. \right\}` with `amsmath` (already included by the `mathtools` package) to obtain the curly brace on the right, and use `\tag` to add the annotation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{rcases}
 first equation\\ \tag{Fermat}
 second equation\\
\end{rcases}
\end{align}
%
\begin{align}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  first equation\\ 
  second equation\\
\end{aligned}
\right\} \tag{Fermat}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but where should I put the annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic number of any line in a math environment can be overridden by a `\tag` command:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:fermat}\tag{Fermat}
\begin{cases}
first equation\\
second equation
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

In this way the tag will go in place of the equation number. If you want instead to add also the annotation, which might be even better,

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:fermat}
\begin{cases}
first equation\\
second equation
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{(Fermat)}
\end{equation}
```

Don't use `align` when you're not doing an alignment (the surrounding spacing is excessive) and don't use a final `\\` in `amsmath` environments (that causes an erroneous vertical space).

Comment: with `amsmath`, don't need `\text` with `\tag` since it's not in math mode.

Comment: Thanks! (I am doing an alignment, but dropped it for this minimal example). I've now used `\label{eq:fermat}\tag{Fermat}`. Interestingly it works even with `align*`; the `*` must take out the number but not what replaces it. Thanks for the `\\` tip too.

Comment: Yes, `\tag` works also in *-environments. With `\eqref{eq:fermat}` you'll get the tag, of course, that is, (Fermat).