# Several lines of formulas to the left of one curly brace pointing to equation number

Tags: spacing, arrays

How to make several lines of equations under one curly brace from the left side, such that it point to a reference number.

Now I do something like this:

```
\begin{align}
\left.
\begin{array}{ll}
a = b + c \\
& \dots  \\
a = b + c \\
& \dots  \\
a = b + c 
\end{array}
\right\} \label{formulas}\\
\end{align}
```

But equation number appears in the bottom of curly brace.

Comment: except for the extra double backslash after the label, this is already addressed by earlier questions: [Curly brace behind equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41843/579) and [How to right-side annotate a bracketed-together set of items in cases environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41843/579)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra line break `\\` to the right of your label. If you delete it, the output should look fine.

[image: sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\left.
\begin{array}{ll}
a = b + c \\
& \dots  \\
a = b + c \\
& \dots  \\
a = b + c 
\end{array}
\right\} \label{formulas}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: no point in using an `align` environment here; an `equation` would do.

Comment: Thank, it was stupid mistake. Did not notice.

Comment: @Jubobs: You're right! Thanks for pointing out. I was trying to stick to OP's codes as close as possible, and didn't even think too much about the environment being used.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `rcases` from the [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) package for this- it loads and extends the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) package.

[image: screenshot]

Code

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{rcases}
    a = b + c \\
      & \dots \\
    a = b + c \\
      & \dots \\
    a = b + c 
    \end{rcases}
    \label{formulas}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```