# Change fontsize of an array within an align environment

Tags: align, fontsize, line-spacing, arrays

I am trying to label several lines at once in a very long equation. From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107313/several-lines-of-formulas-to-the-left-of-one-curly-brace-pointing-to-equation-nu) I have come up with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    x &= \sum_i c_i X_i \\
    &\left. \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{array}{l}
    + \sum_i c_i Y_i \\
    +\sum_i c_i Z_i 
    \end{array} 
    \right\} \tag{From (1)} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which generates

[image: Minimal example]

As you can see I have attempted to correct the fact that array by default will have smaller row spacing than the align*. However, I cannot make the font sizes match up and the line spacing is really not that good either. I have tried using begingroup, endgroup but that doesn't seem to work. I would really appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you can make use of [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)' `drcases` environment (`d` stands for *displaystyle*, while `r` means the brace will be on the right):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    x &= \sum_i c_i X_i \\
      &\hphantom{={}}\!\begin{drcases} % <--- \! is to get correct spacing/alignment
          + \sum_i c_i Y_i \\
          + \sum_i c_i Z_i 
        \end{drcases} 
    \tag{From (1)} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

If you want more space between the math and the brace, you can add `\quad`  (or any other space) to the end of the longest line:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    x &= \sum_i c_i X_i \\
      &\hphantom{={}}\!\begin{drcases} % <--- \! is to get correct spacing/alignment
          + \sum_i c_i Y_i \quad\\
          + \sum_i c_i Z_i 
        \end{drcases} 
    \tag{From (1)} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with more space]

Another possibility (less "automatic") is to give the extra linespacing in square brackets after the `\\` as in `\\[.5em]`, which will give an extra 0.5 em of linespacing after the line you are ending.